# Expo & ReactNative debugger how to make the state visible?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, react-native-debugger

I have a ReactNative app that was setup with Expo/Typescript.

I have downloaded the ReactNativeDebugger.

I have made sure that the versions of ReactNativeDebugger (RND) are aligned with ReactNative.

- Debugger: 0.11.6
- ReactNativeVersion: 0.63.2

I have changed the port of RND to align with expos port (19000) https://docs.expo.io/workflow/debugging/#react-native-debugger.

I have enabled remote debugging inside the expo app.

And it appears that connection with RND and ReactNativeExpo running on Android Physical device is connected:

[image]

However, I am not able to see any of the redux state etc...

Is there any other troubleshooting steps that I can do to actually be able to see redux state in the React Native Debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the part of setup for Redux Dev Tools on the React Native side:

Adding the following to the createStore setup allowed to see the redux state

```
/** https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm */
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const store = createStore(combinedReducers, MyPreloadedState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

From https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm